# Chromium version 53 for ARM gn build issue

Tags: arm, linker-errors, chromium, ninja

I have a problem when building chromium for ARM platform. Here are some details about my host server:

Linux version 4.2.0-42-generic (buildd@lgw01-55) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) )

And I use Chromium version 53.0.2785.143. I tried to use gn to build the chromium, and here is my arguments in args.gn file:

```
target_cpu = "arm"
arm_tune = "generic-armv7-a"
arm_float_abi = "softfp"
```

Basically, I used these specific arguments above because of my ARM platform. And the gn command ran without errors. However, when building project with ninja, the following errors popped out:

> ninja: Entering directory `out/Default_arm64'
>       [1/1] Regenerating ninja files
>       [296/46119] LINK ./minidump-2-core
>       FAILED: minidump-2-core
>       ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -Wl,--fatal-warnings -fPIC -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,defs -fuse-ld=gold -B../../third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -Wl,--icf=all -pthread --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot -L/home/miaozixiong/workspace/chromium/src/build/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
>   -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/miaozixiong/workspace/chromium/src/build/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
>   -L/home/miaozixiong/workspace/chromium/src/build/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
>   -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/miaozixiong/workspace/chromium/src/build/linux/debian_wheezy_arm-sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
>   -Wl,-rpath-link=../Default_arm64 -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -o "./minidump-2-core" -Wl,--start-group @"./minidump-2-core.rsp" 
>   -Wl,--end-group  -ldl -lrt    ld.gold: error: obj/breakpad/minidump-2-core/minidump-2-core.o uses VFP register
>   arguments, output does not
>
> ...

I am new to chromium and have no clue about what do those errors mean. So anybody knows how to work around? You are appreciated.

Note: I need my arm_float_abi attribute to be "softfp" according to my ARM platform. So please note I cannot change it to "hard". Also, when set float abi = "hard", there is no building errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question and finally solved it. I used my local tool chain on ARM platform and compiled it successfully with g++.

Answer (score 0):

> ld.gold: error: obj/breakpad/minidump-2-core/minidump-2-core.o uses VFP register arguments, output does not

This a linking error  to indicate that `minidump-2-core` cannot be linked, due to a mismatch in the floating point ABI: the object `minidump-2-core.o` is compiled for hard floats (the generated code takes advantage of the [ARM VFP unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Floating-point_.28VFP.29) - "uses VFP register arguments"), but the target executable is requested to use soft floats (in which floating point support is emulated, rather than using specialized FP hardware instructions).

According to this [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2140), Chromium should build fine with soft float.

My best guess is, try replacing `softfp` by just `soft`: `arm_float_abi = "soft"`.
According to [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html), `softfp` maintains the soft ABI but still 'allows the generation of code using hardware floating-point instructions', which could lead to the seen error.

If that won't work, you might want to check this tutorial on cross building Chromium for ARM:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176794/how-do-i-cross-compile-chromium-for-arm

Comment: Hello @valiano. Thank you for your reply. I tried arm_float_abi = "soft" option and got the same error. Also, I read the tutorial you mentioned before. Unfortunately, I guess this tutorial is mainly focus on "hard" float way. I am quite new to linux arm cross toolchains, and if I was wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @tonymiao I see... In terms of toolchain, you probably want to install:  
`sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi g++-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabi`, and to remove the HF counterparts `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` and `g++-4.8-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf` in case they were previously installed per the mentioned tutorial.

Comment: Thank you bro, @valiano. I tried the way you mentioned in comment. Still cannot make it. I guess google changed the arm compiler during 2015. I traced a patch here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list which was changing gnueabi to gnueabihf. There were too many relevant changes that I couldn't find them all.